# 3D Pie chart with Label in PHP

Tags: php, 3d, pie-chart

I am using the following package to generate 3D Pie Chart:
http://www.peters1.dk/webtools/php/lagkage.php?sprog=en

But this Chart doesn't have label or percentage over this graph. I would like to display "Denmark, US, Germany etc" over the corresponding graphs.. that will help to identify the percentage very easily.

Please help me or provide any package links which produce similar 3D Pie Chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and seems good.. And produced more clear chart rather than the package I used. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ (free)

or http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Pie-and-Doughnut-Charts.php (costs, but very flexable)

Comment: I changed package and used Google Chart.. And now it works as I expected. Thank you for your reply.. And the Anychart also looks good but I prefer to use Google Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.chartjs.org/, http://www.highcharts.com/https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/index both are pretty easy to integrate. ChartJs uses HTML 5 Canvas to create graphs and you can have 6 different chart types. Highchart is written in pure HTML5/JavaScript. All the best.